Prove that $\mathrm{Frac}(R[x])\cong \mathrm{Frac}(\mathrm{Frac}(\mathrm{R})[x])$

Question:Let $R$ be a domain with $F=\mathrm{Frac}(R)$, prove that
$\mathrm{Frac}(R[x])\cong F(x)$,i.e.$$\mathrm{Frac}(R[x])\cong
 \mathrm{Frac}(\mathrm{Frac}(\mathrm{R})[x])$$

My try:Consider the following mapping:$$\begin{align}&\varphi:\mathrm{Frac}(\mathrm{Frac}(\mathrm{R})[x])\to \text{Frac}(R[x])\\h=
&\frac{\sum_{k=0}^n[a_k,b_k]x^k}{\sum_{k=0}^m[c_k,d_k]x^k}\mapsto\varphi(h)=\frac{\prod_{j=1}^md_j}{\prod_{j=1}^nb_j}\bigg(\frac{\prod_{j=1}^nb_j}{\prod_{j=1}^md_j}\frac{\sum_{k=0}^n[a_k,b_k]x^k}{\sum_{k=0}^m[c_k,d_k]x^k}\bigg)&
\end{align}$$Where $a_k,b_k\in R$ and $[a_k,b_k]\in \text{Frac}(R)$($b_k$ is the denominator)
But I find it hard to verify $\varphi(h+g)=\varphi(h)+\varphi(g)$:$$\begin{align}
h+g&=\frac{\sum_{k=0}^n[a^1_k,a^2_k]x^k}{\sum_{k=0}^m[b^1_k,b^2_k]x^k}+\frac{\sum_{k=0}^p[c^1_k,c^2_k]x^k}{\sum_{k=0}^l[d^1_k,d^2_k]x^k}\\&=\frac{(\sum_{k=0}^n[a^1_k,a^2_k]x^k)(\sum_{k=0}^l[d^1_k,d^2_k]x^k)+(\sum_{k=0}^n[c^1_k,c^2_k]x^k)(\sum_{k=0}^p[b^1_k,b^2_k]x^k)}{(\sum_{k=0}^m[b^1_k,b^2_k]x^k)(\sum_{k=0}^l[d^1_k,d^2_k]x^k)}
\end{align}$$However,it seems like the formula above is hard to compute.Did I choose a right mapping?If so,is there a more elegant way to finish this proof?
Any help would be appreciated.

That is quite a complicated method. One could brute force from there but there are better ways.
One way is to use universal properties. Consider the inclusion map $R[x]\to F(x)$. Then, the image of any nonzero element is invertible so we get a ring map $\operatorname{Frac}(R[x])\to F(x)$ sending $f/g\mapsto f/g$. (You should understand what $f/g$ means in each context.)
On the other hand, we have an inclusion $F\to\operatorname{Frac}(R[x])$. By universal property, we get a map $F(x)\to\operatorname{Frac}(R[x])$ sending $x\mapsto x$. Verify that this is a two-sided inverse of the earlier map.
Hope this helps. :>
